# how to assign to session a value from a click in a list in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a list of books, rendered as it follows:
(view .erb file)

```
<% @books.list_new['books'].each do |book| %>
<p class="title is-4"><%= link_to book['title'], book['url'] %></p>
<%= link_to "Create a post!", new_post_path, :onclick => session[:isbn] = book["isbn13"], class:"button" %>
<% end %>
```

WHAT I NEED: when clicking on the button, copy the isbn13 value of that specific book to the session so that when you are sent to the form through link_to helper, the isbn field of the form is prefilled with the isbn value of that specific book

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>

<%= f.input :isbn, input_html: {class: 'integer', value: session['isbn']}, wrapper: false, label_html: {class: 'label'} %>
<% end %>
```

PROBLEM: the input field if prefilled, but with the isbn13 value of the last book in the list, not with the isbn13 value of the book/button I wanted

thanks for helping a newbee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why everything feels like `Hash`. I'll assume *Book* is a model and *list_new* is a ... something:

```rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  scope :recent, ->(time) { where("created_at > ?", time) }
end
```

Don't need session here, just send it in the url:

```rb
<% @books.recent(10.days.ago).each do |book| %>
  <%= link_to book.title, book.url %>
  <%= link_to "new post", new_post_path(isbn: book.isbn13) %>
<% end %>
```

Now if you click "new post", it takes you to `/posts/new?isbn=9783161484100` path:

```rb
# The url query string is available in `params`.

# Because this form is tied to the model, it is much simpler to set the
# value on the model and let form builder set values on the fields.
# You can do this in the controller action as well.

<% @post.isbn ||= params[:isbn] %>

<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :isbn %>
<% end %>

# FYI: there is a simple form initializer, you can configure things there:
# config/initializers/simple_form.rb
config.label_class = "label"
```